# How to create a connection between two virtual networks?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to join a VM to a to a managed domain On Azure. I have checked on a Microsoft page but my issue it can be different. I can do a ping to 123test.com because it is a website and I am receiving a public IP address 69.x.x.x

I think that could be a cause of this issue. When I am trying to confirm by OK button I am receiving the error:

> An Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for the domain
>   "123test.com" could not be contacted. Ensure that the domain name is
>   typed correctly.
>
> Note: This information is intended for a network administrator.  If
>   you are not your network's administrator, notify the administrator
>   that you received this information, which has been recorded in the
>   file C:\windows\debug\dcdiag.txt.
>
> The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service
>   location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory
>   Domain Controller (AD DC) for domain "123test.com":
>
> The error was: "DNS name does not exist." (error code 0x0000232B
>   RCODE_NAME_ERROR)
>
> The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.123test.com
>
> Common causes of this error include the following:
>
> - The DNS SRV records required to locate an AD DC for the domain are not registered in DNS. These records are registered with a DNS server
>     automatically when an AD DC is added to a domain. They are updated by
>     the AD DC at set intervals. This computer is configured to use DNS
>     servers with the following IP addresses:
>
> 168.63.129.16
>
> - One or more of the following zones do not include delegation to its child zone:
>
> 123test.com
>
> com . (the root zone)

Answer (score 0):

you can workaround by using a hosts file inside your vm (to force this dns to resolve to IP of your domain controller), or you can configure your vnet to use your DC as a DNS server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#specify-dns-servers

Comment: Your advice wasn't helpful in this specific issue.

Comment: care to expand a little bit?

Comment: The documentation link provided is correct, maybe it's the explanation that isn't clear.  By default, Azure Vnets use Azure provided DNS to do name resolution.  When you decide to use your own Domain Controllers, you need to add your DC's (best practice is n+1 DC's for redundancy) IP address to the VNet as a DNS server so you can domain join.  You can always forward DNS from you DC back to Azure as documented in the link provided.

Comment: I have one VM in different subnet what DNS servers are. This is a problem. Are any services to connect between two subnets?

Comment: if they are in different subnets of the same vnet it will just work, if they are in different vnets you can use vnet peering (easiest) and site-to-site vpn. vnet ip address ranges have to not overlap

Comment: I have VM and I would like to join to the managed domain. I can't because I have connectivity issue on VM do domain 123test.com. 

The virtual network is the same but subnets are not the same and I am not able to join VM to domain anyway.

My Azure AD Domain Services has Resource Group 'RGroup01' with Virtual Network 'VN01'.
VN01\default subnet

My VM has the same  Resource Group 'RGroup01' with Virtual Network 'VN01'.
VN01\Azure_services subnet

Comment: unless you explicitly blocked access with nsg things inside vnet can talk to each other (or you have some weird udr)

Comment: In NSG I see rules: 
AllowVnetInBound and  AllowVnetOutBound any, any Source=VirtualNetwork, Destination=VirtualNetwork
It is a default rule created by Azure...

Comment: yep, that means connectivity is there, you just need to configure dns resolution